# Timer not resetting

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, timer

I have a simple program to detect when a file is created in a directory. It is supposed to check every minute if there is a new file, then reset the timer if there isn't a new file.

```
import os
import threading
import time
import sys

def detector():
    filenames = os.listdir('/home/username/Documents/')
    if filenames:
        for i in filenames:
            #do things
    print('I started a thread!')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    threading.Thread(target=start_timer).start()
def start_timer():
    print('I started a threaded timer at', t.ctime())
    sys.stdout.flush()
    threading.Timer(60, detector)
#UI stuff here
```

When run with no files in the directory, the script just prints out:

```
I started a thread!
I started a timer at [insert time here]
```

But only once. Which makes me think that there is something wrong with my threading (I have never used threading before). I don't know if it must be threaded, but the program can't wait for a normal timer because a timer makes the UI hang until the timer is done.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by setting the target of thread created at the end of `detector` to be `start_timer` and then setting the callback of `Timer` to be `detector`? By the way, `Timer` is a subclass of `Thread`, so to start it you must in theory call `start`...

Comment: Oh...yeah....start...I was hoping to start a timer to check if a file was created without having the UI hang.

Comment: Multithreading is not a trivial programming task. You must first understand the basics...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example of what I think you want:

```
import os
import threading


def list_dir(my_dir, secs):

    filenames = os.listdir(my_dir)
    # print(filenames)

    # Do your stuff here!!!

    # Setting a new timer: call list_dir in secs seconds
    threading.Timer(secs, list_dir, args=[my_dir, secs]).start()

def start_timer():
    print('timer started!')
    seconds = 60  # 60 seconds
    directory = "/my/beloved/dir"  # insert here the directory
    threading.Timer(seconds, list_dir, args=[directory, seconds]).start()


start_timer()
```

Notice that `Timer` only calls its callback once (after the amount of seconds that you specify as first parameter), and this is why we create and start another `Timer` inside `list_dir`.

Comment: I will test it in the morning. But the important thing is: Does the timer halt the program until it's finished (e.g: will theoretical UI buttons still work?) EDIT: Once I check the answer in the morning, I'll accept the answer.